# html - whey the radio buttons are getting selected multiple times instead of one radio box?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I need to have 4 radio buttons but not multiple selection. Only one selection which is not happening.

code:

```
    <form id="fieldone_form">

<label for="field1"><input type="radio" id="field1" name="a" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',1);">Call </label><br>
<label for="field2"><input type="radio" id="field2" name="b" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',2);">Mail </label><br>
<label for="field3"><input type="radio" id="field3" name="c" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',3);">Rejected </label><br>
<label for="field4"><input type="radio" id="field4" name="d" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',4);">Not met</label><br>

    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Group them by giving them all the same name value.

Comment: YES - name value when i set all to 'a' then its working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are grouped by their `name` attribute, so you must not use different names.

This will allow only one of your buttons to be selected at once:

```
<form id="fieldone_form">
    <label for="field1"><input type="radio" id="field1" name="a" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',1);">Call </label><br>
    <label for="field2"><input type="radio" id="field2" name="a" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',2);">Mail </label><br>
    <label for="field3"><input type="radio" id="field3" name="a" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',3);">Rejected </label><br>
    <label for="field4"><input type="radio" id="field4" name="a" onclick="text_select_fieldonedone('6','bre1_6',4);">Not met</label><br>
</form>
```